# Count table rows with special "keyword" (SQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **SQL-table** called **"usermeta"**, inside this table are lots of columns and rows. I need the **column "meta_key"** and want to **count** the rows with the **keyword "Users"**.

Whats wrong with my script?

```
<?php
$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(meta_key) AS Users FROM $wpdb->usermeta" );
echo "<p>Users count: {$user_count}</p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL query should be

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT meta_key) FROM  usermeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%Users%'
```

and since we did not want unique results

> I always get "1" - does it only counts this entry once? – Pepe

and code should be therefore

```
<?php
$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(meta_key) AS Users FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key like '%Users%'" );
echo "<p>Users count: {$user_count}</p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a WHERE clause to filter for rows with have your keyword. For a detailed answer you should explain more one how your table actually looks like.